# why does function() need to be typed before the function name when using onkeydown in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I was practicing a bit with events on W3Schools. In their tutorial, they show this line of code:

```html
document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

I don't understand why you have to type function() {function name()} rather than just typing the function you are trying to call. Basically, I'm not understanding the logic behind that line of code. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: The outer function isn't being called just yet, its being defined. It'll get called on the event trigger

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `function`, you can just put the function name there.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input id="demo">
```

You would need to wrap it inside another function if you wanted to do more than just call the function directly.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = function() {
  console.log("Keydown");
  myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input id="demo">
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can do it*, you must pass it as reference:

`document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction();` - `myFunction` will be called immediately and not as callback. Callback would be return value of `myFunction`.

You them assign it as reference:

`document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction` - note that you can't pass parameters at runtime here!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give:

```html
document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

the value of the onkeydown property of an element must be a function - not a call to a function. So you could not have for example:

```
  document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction();
```

What that would do would be to try to run myFunction and put the result from that into the onkeydown property.

Actually it would fail as at the time the system tried to run it that function doesn't yet exist.

What you could do is declare the function first and then use that as the value for the assignment.

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction;
```

Comment: Oh I see. So just to make sure I understand correctly: In the line document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = myFunction(); I am not calling myFunction, I am literally assigning the onkeydown to a call, which would result in an error. By typing function() {myFunction()} I am assigning onkeydown to the function itself, which is what makes the rest of the code work. Did I get that right?

Comment: You have an error in the code in your comment. There should be no brackets after myFunction. But otherwise yes, you are right you aren’t calling the function, you are just setting the value to that function so the function can be run later when the event happens..